# Retrieve and input data

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, datagridview

I'm making a sales invoicing program using `VB.NET`. The input form looks as follows when creating a new invoice: [data_input_form](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vft2xpw2f3ezfe6/input_screen.JPG)

The table you see in the middle is the a `datagridview control`. [`Link to Model`](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1uixgyktegmbw45/db_model.JPG)

Instead of using a SQL query to get the columns I made them using the properties just to get an idea of what I want to achieve.

What I want is...

1. The user to be able to select product names using the combo-box inside the datagridview. Any ideas how I can create a connection and do it?
2. The description and unit price columns should also be populated upon choosing a product name as appropriate.
3. Implement a formula (total price = quantity * unit price) showing the result under the total price column.

Just in case you're wondering about my database structure, here's a relational model of it:
[db_relational_model](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1uixgyktegmbw45/db_model.JPG)

I'm not sure how to get started with this. Any help would be appriciated. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Was my answer helpful? If not, please specify anything else you would like. If it was helpful, please mark it correct.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the links you've given. I had a quick look through them and they look relevant. Sorry for my late response, have been quite busy lately.

Comment: No problem. Have fun coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To bind a `DataGridView` see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fbk67b6z(v=vs.90).aspx

To find a suitable connection string for your server, see http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

To simply connect to a data base, see the following example for guidance: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8477/Using-ADO-NET-for-beginners

Hope this helps.